# vertical align for three divs floated in one div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

i'd like to align vertically three divs of a container div, but all the 3 divs inside the container are floated, one in right, one in center and one in left, to make a navbar.

I saw all the navbars in bootstrap and I'd like to take 3 navbars divs and put it in one div to make a navbar.

I am a beginner of HTML code, so i hope you all can help me.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 11px !important;
}

.sinistra {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 7%;
  background-color: white !important;
  line-height: 10%;
  vertical-align: center;
}

.centro {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 30%;
  height: 7%;
  line-height: 10%;
  vertical-align: center;
}

.destra {
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  height: 7%;
  line-height: 10%;
  vertical-align: center;
}

a {
  font-size: 11px !important;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="sinistra">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="/docs/5.1/assets/brand/bootstrap-logo.svg" alt="" width="30" height="24" class="d-inline-block align-text-top"> aaaa
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="centro"> <a>aaa</a></div>
    <div class="destra">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" aria-current="page" href="#">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li>
              <hr class="dropdown-divider">
            </li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: float and vertical-align are not compatible, look at display options for that ;) *(inline-block, inline-x, table,table-cell,grid,flex )*

Answer (score 1):

For the love of all things holy, just dispense with floats altogether. They're old and troublesome and anathema to the whole idea of the Bootstrap layout system. Any tutorial that suggests them should be disregarded.

Also, you seem to be recreating wheels here. [This is all available out of the box](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/).

Here's the ticket:

1. Use a proper container/row/column structure, per [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/grid/).
2. Put the class `align-items-center` on the row. This vertically aligns the contents.
3. Put the class `flex-fill` on the menu column. This lets it take all available space. I've also applied class `justify-content-end` to the nav element to align its tabs right.

Notice... absolutely no custom CSS needed.

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row flex-nowrap align-items-center">
      <div class="col sinistra">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="" width="30" height="24" class="d-inline-block align-text-top"> aaaa
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="col centro">
        <a>aaa</a>
      </div>

      <div class="col flex-fill destra">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-end">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" aria-current="page" href="#">Active</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li>
                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
              </li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: op is a beginner and only mentions bootstrap in passing in question.

Comment: beginners are better served learning basic html css and javascript then relying on libraries.  The documentation (including bootstrap) is confusing in places.  relying on libraries creates overhead and code that's harder to manage. Just my opinion but that's how I see it.

Answer (score -1):

Use flexbox

```css
#container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;  
  align-items:center;
  width:100%;
  height:30vh;
  justify-content:space-evenly;
  
  }
  
  div{
  border:solid 2px red;
  width:25%;
  text-align:center;
  
  }
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div>c</div>
</div>
```

Comment: None of that's necessary with Bootstrap. Don't write custom CSS when your library already offers the tools.

Comment: don't use libraries when you don't have to.